# Saving SVG as PDF causes disappearance of centralized graphics

Tags: inkscape, svg, pdf

When I save my SVG file as a pdf with Inkscape or other converting tools like cloud convert etc. the graphic in the center is disappearing or it will be deleted respectively.

I tried different ways to fix that problem, like converting the element into a path or firstly save the SVG file as a png, tiff, jpeg etc. but nothing worked. When I click on ,,release mask", and save the SVG as a PDF, the element is visible but not in the given opacity but in the full intensity.

What can I do to fix that problem?

The SVG:
https://jmp.sh/s/kdysaXt3Pi717GSSlQ0Q

Answer (score 3):

There's something wrong with the large graphic. It's a `<use>` element, so either a clone or a symbol, and it seems to have a filter applied. I can't be 100% sure, though. For some unknown reason I can't unlink the clone or convert it to paths or remove the filter. Perhaps it wasn't made in Inkscape, some other software?

Anyway, a possible fix is simply to delete it and replace it. Make a copy of the actual graphic (the solid blue one at the top), group it, scale it, place it at the centre, and reduce the object opacity in the Fill and Stroke dialog. I tried this and can confirm it solves the problem. I checked PDF in Adobe Acrobat and it seems to work

[image]

**Edit** After a little further investigation, PDFs created in Inkscape do in fact support `<use>` elements in the form of linked clones or symbols, and objects with SVG effects are normally rasterized when outputing to PDF. So these shouldn't normally pose a problem. However, the file doesn't appear to have been created in Inkscape originally, and somehow the functionality appears to be messed up. Usually it would be possible to unlink a clone, but for some reason Inkscape doesn't want to do it.  So ultimately, the issue seems to be caused by a combination of things: the use of an SVG effect on a messed up linked element created in some other software. There are too many unknowns to be 100% sure however.

Just a word of advice for the future. If you have artwork that has been created in other software (not Inkscape), it may be better to use a PDF created directly using that software rather than export as SVG to use in Inkscape and then convert to PDF. This workflow is often fraught with difficulties, mainly because different software has different support for various SVG features.  Note also that Inskcape isn't really designed for print jobs. It lacks CMYK and spot colour support, so chances are the PDF you output from Inkscape won't actually work for a print job where separations are needed, at least not without first taking it into software such as Scribus, and editing the colours.

I also note another potential problem with the artwork file you shared here: the objects which bleed off the top and bottom page haven't been set up properly. If it's your intention to have this commercially printed, these should overlap the edge of the sheet by at least 3mm. A commercial print company will then print this on a larger sheet, and trim it to size. If you don't set up a bleed and try to have this printed, it won't work.  A printer would probably charge you extra if they have to fix it for you.